# Как удалить вводимое число из списка python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, break

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что есть код

```
items = []

while True:
    n = int(input())
    items.append(n)
    
    if  n==0:
        break
    
print(items)
```

То есть я пытаюсь из ввода исключить вводимый 0, к примеру :

```
Ввод 
12
13
14
0

Вывод:
12
13
14
```

Пытался сам, увы не хватает понимания, пытался применять условие или remove, но ничего не получается :(

Comment: поставьте if перед append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
items = []

while True:
    n = int(input('Введите целое число, 0(ноль) - выход: '))
#    items.append(n)                                          # ---
    
    if  not n:
        break
        
    items.append(n)                                           # +++    
    
print(*items, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо)Это и в правду помогло!

Comment: @ИванИванов пожалуйста